# Imitating .bash_history in python 2.x

Tags: python, linux

I was wondering if there was a way to "imitate" the linux .bash_history.
It would be something like:

```
def write_history(cmd):
try:
    with open("/root/.python_history","a") as history:
        history.write(str(cmd) + "\n")
        history.close()
except:
    with open("/root/.python_history","w") as history:
        history.write(str(cmd) + "\n")
        history.close()

while 1:
    cmd = raw_input("cmd > ")
    write_history(cmd)
    if cmd.lower() == "exit":
        exit()
    elif cmd.lower() == "yay":
        print("YAY !")
    elif keyup.is.pressed:              #it's to do this that I need help
        read_the_last_line_of_python_history()  #and this too
```

Can you help me pls ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`cmd`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/cmd.html) module for the shell and [`readline`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/readline.html) for the history:

```
import cmd
import sys
import os.path
import readline

histfn = os.path.expanduser('~/.mycmd.history')

class MyCmd(cmd.Cmd):
    def __init__(self):
        cmd.Cmd.__init__(self)
        try:
            readline.read_history_file(histfn)
        except IOError:
            pass

    def do_yay(self, arg):
        print('YAY !')

    def do_exit(self, arg):
        readline.write_history_file(histfn)
        sys.exit(0)

    def do_EOF(self, arg):
        print()
        self.do_exit(arg)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyCmd().cmdloop()
```

Comment: thx it works but the problem is that is wrote a 300 lines script and in order to do it your way, I would have to rewrite all the script. Is there an easier way, something like I written in the top message ?

Comment: The `cmd` module is *the* standard module from the standard library for this purpose. Therefore, you should use it. It supports all the readline functionalities that advanced users expect, including searching in past commands and the like.
There is no way to get key presses using `raw_input`, that is simply the wrong tool for the job. In any case, adding the readline functionality to your program would be orders of magnitudes harder than running a simple search-and-replace to convert your if-tree to do_* methods.